# Angular: @Input não funciona com select/mat-select

Tags: angular, angularjs-directives

Olá, estou criando componentes reutilizáveis com angular 8, e necessito a troca de parâmetros entre eles usando o decorator @Input, porem isto não funciona quando uso mat-select ou select nativo uma vez que as opções não aparecem.

Veja meu código:

Chamada do componente:

```
<i-select data="{{selectData | json}}" label="selectLabel"></i-select>
```

Componente i-select:

```
@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: component-selector
  selector: 'i-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any;

  @Input() label: string;

  @Output() event = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.data !== undefined) {
      this.data = JSON.parse(this.data);
    }
  }
}
```

E o meu SelectComponentHtml:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let content of data" [value]="content.chave">
        {{content.value}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

O que está errado?

Comment: pq vc esta passando como json e depois fazendo parse?

Comment: De acordo com os meus testes, se eu não coloco o | json ali, o que me retorna é um [Object Object], e e no parse é pq o valor enviado na chamada do componente é um tipo string, esse é o motivo.